# How do you say "to have a tire rotation" in German?

Tags: idiom

> Tomorrow I am going to have my tires rotated because the tires in front
>   are worn out

Morgen werde ich die Reifen meines Autos umstecken lassen, da die Reifen von vorne abgenutzt sind.

Does "die Reifen meines Autos umstecken lassen" mean `to have tire rotation` in German? And I am not sure that the word `abgenutzt` means "worn out."

Comment: Please, before you go on yet another spree of simple translation questions, remember that you need to show the results of your own research efforts and explain where you got stuck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Reifenwechsel" is the common term, although "[Radwechsel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radwechsel)" is probably correct in this context. You can also use "durchwechseln" or "umstecken".

> Morgen werde ich meine Räder umstecken lassen weil die Vorderreifen abgefahren sind.

Comment: Morgen werde ich einen Radwechsel durchwechseln lassen, da die Vorderreifen abgenutzt sind? Danke!

Comment: "einen Radwechsel durchführen lassen" or "meine Räder durchwechseln lassen".

Comment: First thing I would think of with "Rad-/Reifenwechsel" would be a tire _replacement_ though. Use "durchwechseln" or "umstecken" to avoid confusion.

Comment: Danke sehr für die Hilfe!

Comment: Is 'umstecken' more of a slang term or proper german? Because I've never heard it, which is weird.

Comment: It's the term used by professionals. A layman would rather use "durchwechseln".

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the proposed *Reifenwechsel*, since it too generic. It applies to changing the whole set against winter tyres, replacement of a punctured single tyre and so on.

Since the tyres are also typically mounted on rims, even for this my workshop prefers to call it *Räderwechsel* instead.

As you may refer [here](https://www.auto-motor-und-sport.de/verkehr/reifen-verschleiss-laengere-lebensdauer-dank-positionswechsel/), *Positionswechsel* or *Rädertausch* seem better matches. Since in modern tyres the direction of rotation is fixed anyway, putting a tyre from the left to the right would no longer be possible anyway (the clockwise rotation no longer being possible), so *Rädertausch* (i. e. swapping of tyres, between front and back axis) seems most precise term.